# list hover megamenu hiding not able to select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hi dear all i am working with megamenu i just write a code instead of download and adding the code .i just write the code for display mega menu div on menu hover .it is working fine but i had a problem . after hover one div displaying but it is not able to select content in the mega menu.i don't know how to write the code in jquery when ever hover the list it si allow to select the content also. 
when i try to hover in the down megamenu when cursor moves it is hiding.

MY HTML Code

```
 <div class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="tech">Chipsets</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="tech">Wireless Modules</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="tech">Divices & Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="tech">IP Licensing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="tech">Technology</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <div class="megamenu">Content here11.Services..1</div>
<div class="megamenu">Content here222.Training..2</div>
<div class="megamenu">Content here..Communities.3</div>
<div class="megamenu">Content here..Store.4</div>
<div class="megamenu">Content here..Store.5</div>
```

JQuery Code

```
$('.tech').hover(function(){
            divTrigger = $('.tech').index(this);            
         $('.megamenu:eq('+divTrigger+')').show();
    },function(){
         $('.megamenu:eq('+divTrigger+')').hide();      

        });
```

JSBIN link http://jsbin.com/IyUhUYi/2/edit

can any one solve my problem .

Answer (score 0):

first try to use nested li and style it with css so it looks like a dropdown list instead of hover div because currently your code says that on hover show this div theres no code that says its actually a dropdown or selectable div and the moment you move your cursor away it will just go away

Comment: i want to take saparate divs which is not included in list

Comment: Then insert the div inside that li so it still understands that the div is a part of ur li and in this way it wont dissapear and you will be able to click on it just include a link inside a link which can b clicked

Answer (score 0):

it is best to do that and remove jquery

```
<div class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="tech">Chipsets</a>
             <div class="megamenu">Content here11.Services..1</div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="tech">Wireless Modules</a>
              <div class="megamenu">Content here222.Training..2</div>
          </li>
          ....
        </ul>
      </div>
```

and use this css

```
.menu ul li div
{
   display:none;
}

.menu ul li:hover div
{
    display:block;
}
```